# mysql error (HY000):file not found (Errcode: 2)

Tags: mysql, database, loading, putty, error-code

So I'm trying to load my database by loading .txt file (fields terminated by \t). But it keeps sending me this error:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:\\tvshow.txt" INTO TABLE SERIJA FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
ERROR 2 (HY000): File 'C:\tvshow.txt' not found (Errcode: 2)
```

Can somebody help me out?

(I'm using PuTTY on Windows 10)

Comment: remove `LOCAL` and try

Comment: @harshavmb I tried,doesn't work